# Lightning: Add custom button beside new

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible for me to add a custom button in the highlighted box? When user clicks on the custom button, it will trigger a lightning component.[image]

Comment: Look at object based quick actions and how to hook up lightning components to the quick actions

Comment: @Rao object based quick actions only allows button within the record page. But I want the button at the listing page instead of record page.

Comment: @WenHao and you need to map that quick action in page layout.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a direct way to add a button that calls a `Lightning Component` directly from `List Screen`.

A round-about way, but you can follow this method to achieve this.

1. From **Object Manager>Select Your Custom Object > Search Layout > Edit**
   You will see a link to create a list button.

   [image]
2. Now when you create the button. Select the Content Source as Visual Force page. We don't have a option to select a lightning component here**(**Refer below**)
3. Add the button to the Search Layout:
   enter image description here

   [image]
4. The button now will appear as shown below:

   [image]

> **Now for the Lightning Component part, you will have to import the lightning component into a visualforce page: See [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/workshop-lightning-programmatic/steps/programmatic-step-6) link for
>   details on how to import a ligtning componet to Visualforce Page.

Answer (score 1):

In **Object Manager**, navigate to **Opportunity** -> **Search layouts**(left side ) -> **Edit** the List View record.

When edit the list view you will see your custom button add it to selected and save it. Now you will see the custom button on the page.

Regards,
Akshay